# Database schema for blog comment

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I have a comment table on my blog.

```
comment
- id (PK)
- post_id (FK)
- user_id (FK)
- comment
```

Should I split into 3 tables and do it like this?

```
comment
- id (PK)
- comment

user_comment
- comment_id (PK, FK)
- user_id (PK, FK)

post_comment
- post_id (PK, FK)
- comment_id (PK, FK)
```

Would this be a better design? Any other suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: you are going to hit performance problems if trying to show the whole tree, if it's big. you should look into nested set or recursive query techniques. hopefully you are not using mysql, so that you can use recursive query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original design is perfect; it models what is actually going on.

Also, it's good to avoid schema bloat.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first design is far better; splitting that table up adds no value as far as I can tell, and will just force the DB engine to use one or two extra joins for every query.

If you're concerned about performance, you could create indices on the *comment* table to allow efficient selection of comments per user and per post.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table photo_comments(
    commentID int not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    userID int not null,
    photoId int not null,
    comment_data varchar(200)
 )
```

Couldn't you use this?

Comment: Woops...I didn't realise that you pretty much always had this. Im making a comments table now and that's the way I'm doing it.

How did your table work in the end? Did you have to change it when there were too many records?